# DynamoDB Query Returns Incomplete Data

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Why does my query in Lambda not return everything between the two Timestamps? It consistently returns the same, incomplete data.

In DynamoDB Item Explorer, I can query recent Timestamps and find the appropriate items by Device.

When I query in my Lambda, much of that same data is missing.

```
var params = {
   Statement : `SELECT * FROM temps WHERE "Timestamp" >= ${fromParam} AND "Timestamp" <= ${toParam}`,
}
 
dynamodb.executeStatement(params, function(err, data) { ...
```

My DynamoDB table looks like this:

[image: DynamoDB Table 'temps']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDB will only read (note read, not the same as return) 1MB of data at a time.

If you are doing any filtering, then the returned data will be less than the 1MB read.

If there's more data to read, DDB will include `LastEvaluatedKey` in it's response.  You'll need to call `Query()` again passing in the returned `LastEvaluatedKey` as `ExclusiveStartKey`

Thus, unless you can guarantee you'll never have more than 1MB of data to read, you'll want to call `Query()` in a loop till you get back all the data.

**EDIT**
Yes, if nextToken is returned, you'll need to pass that back in the next call..
[image]

I've never used execute statement, but it appears you're doing a full table scan.  Rather than a query.  You need to include a `where device =`  in [order to use query behind the scenes.](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html)

If you really need records for all devices, consider a adding a GSI with a single value as the partition key and timestamp as the sort key.  Then use `FROM TEMPS.mytsidx`

Comment: My incomplete responses to `executeStatement` can be as small as 4k. I don't see `LastEvaluationKey` but I'm getting a property `NextToken` -- same thing?

Comment: Thanks - that's it. I'm amazed that dynamoDB turns a few hundred records into MBs of data 

Comment: @JoeBeuckman DDB is not a RDBMS, nor can it be used like one.

Comment: I thought this was a decent nosql application - timeseries of small documents with no joins. Am I using this wrong?

Comment: Depends on how you need to access the data, see the (updated) GSI recommendation.

Comment: I guess another way to prevent the scan is to make Device a separate property and use a single value for Partition ID.

Comment: correct, that's what my GSI recommendation mentions.  Alternatively, for a different use case of time series data, be sure to read  the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html)

Comment: Heh - I am back to your GSI recommendation. I set up a new partition key but forgot that I needed multiple device readings per timestamp. Thanks again.